# "Got" or "been"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference?

- *I have never played COD and not got greeted with toxicity.*
- *I have never played COD and not been greeted with toxicity.*

Comment: get greeted is not good most of the time, were greeted/was greeted.

Answer (score 1):

The *get* passive is exactly the same as the *be* passive, except that it is less formal.

In your examples, I have a strong preference for *been*, but I think that is mostly for aesthetic reasons - the low vowels of *COD* (if it's pronounced as a word - I have no idea what it is), *not*, *tox-*.

I find *greeted with toxicity* a particularly awkward and unnatural phrase anyway.